# How to use Microsoft Account in an openID site?

Tags: openid, live, hotmail

I am planning to build a site with openID authentication , most of my target users will register in the site using Microsoft accounts (hotmail/live/windowslive).

Is there anyway to use Microsoft accounts as openID?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as i know they still only use their "Passport"/"Windows Live ID" system, so no. They have announced however that they are going to support OpenID at one point or another. Take a look at the link below there is even a Tech Preview to test out their implementation maybe that can be used somehow:

[Microsoft & OpenID](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/microsoft_windows_live_openid.php)

Comment: Has there been any movement on this? All I can find is this from 1 year ago: http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1791.entry It says that you will be able to put live.com in an openID login, but it doesn't seem to work yet.

Comment: It seems like they either lost steam or just don't care. Everyone else at this point has some sort of openID integration. I can't seem to find anything on OpenID and Microsoft since 2008.

Comment: Apparently they'll be supporting OAuth 2.0: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/developer/archive/2011/05/04/announcing-support-for-oauth-2-0.aspx

Comment: any update on this? Last comment is from June, and I haven't found anything new. I know I have a bunch of hotmail users that would love to be able to openid connect to my app.  Can someone provide an update to this?

Comment: From what i can tell there are are no plans to continue this development. I was looking around the net and found most of the links from that article to be broken. Specifically the microsoft link now returns a 500. Must not be too high on their to-do list if they are planning on keeping it around. I wouldn't count on it though!

Comment: This answer is out of date and therefore mis-leading. Please read this blog post by Microsoft: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/23/for-developers-the-first-use-cases-of-the-converged-microsoft-account-and-azure-active-directory-programming-model-are-now-ga/

Answer (score 2):

Until Microsoft supports OpenID my current plan is to hide OpenID and Windows Live ID behind a "Third Party Auth" interface.  Using the Chain of Responsibility pattern I'll choose the correct provider and the rest of the app won't know the difference (except the UI where I'll have friendly buttons, much like the ones for Gmail and Yahoo accounts).

Comment: RPXNow is now 'JanRain Engage' which is a commercial service, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2016, OpenID Connect is supported by Microsoft Accounts (aka Windows Live ID, aka Microsoft Passport), without needing an Azure account.

Please read this:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/23/for-developers-the-first-use-cases-of-the-converged-microsoft-account-and-azure-active-directory-programming-model-are-now-ga/

Comment: How do we actually use OpenID with a Microsoft account though?